# Finding size of distinct array column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Scala and Spark to create a dataframe. Here's my code so far:

```
 val df = transformedFlattenDF
.groupBy($"market", $"city", $"carrier").agg(count("*").alias("count"), min($"bandwidth").alias("bandwidth"), first($"network").alias("network"), concat_ws(",", collect_list($"carrierCode")).alias("carrierCode")).withColumn("carrierCode", split(($"carrierCode"), ",").cast("array<string>")).withColumn("Carrier Count", collect_set("carrierCode"))
```

The column carrierCode becomes an array column. The data is present as follows:

```
CarrierCode
1: [12,2,12]
2: [5,2,8]
3: [1,1,3]
```

I'd like to create a column that counts the number of distinct values in each array. I tried doing `collect_set`, however, it gives me an error saying `grouping expressions sequence is empty` Is it possible to find the number of distinct values in each row's array? So that way in our same example, there could be a column like so:

```
Carrier Count
1: 2
2: 3
3: 2
```

Comment: Could you please provide schema and sample data for transformedFlattenDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collect_set` is for aggregation hence should be applied within your `groupBy-agg` step:

```
val df = transformedFlattenDF.groupBy($"market", $"city", $"carrier").agg(
    count("*").alias("count"), min($"bandwidth").alias("bandwidth"),
    first($"network").alias("network"),
    concat_ws(",", collect_list($"carrierCode")).alias("carrierCode"),
    size(collect_set($"carrierCode")).as("carrier_count")  // <-- ADDED `collect_set`
  ).
  withColumn("carrierCode", split(($"carrierCode"), ",").cast("array<string>"))
```

If you don't want to change the existing `groupBy-agg` code, you can create a UDF like in the following example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val codeDF = Seq(
  Array("12", "2", "12"),
  Array("5", "2", "8"),
  Array("1", "1", "3")
).toDF("carrier_code")

def distinctElemCount = udf( (a: Seq[String]) => a.toSet.size )

codeDF.withColumn("carrier_count", distinctElemCount($"carrier_code")).
  show
// +------------+-------------+
// |carrier_code|carrier_count|
// +------------+-------------+
// | [12, 2, 12]|            2|
// |   [5, 2, 8]|            3|
// |   [1, 1, 3]|            2|
// +------------+-------------+
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your solution! Your second example works, but I'm afraid the first one doesn't work because originally this data is an array of arrays. I make it into a string and then concatenate it with a "," and then concatenate again with "," (I didn't show the first concatenation because I wanted to make a simple question). Knowing this information, is it possible to create something like your first solution?

Comment: Not sure I understand your described data structure.  I would suggest that you assemble a separate question with sample data that better reflects your actual data structure, along with specific aggregation requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Without UDF and using RDD conversion and back to DF for posterity:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
         ("A", 2, 100, 2), ("F", 7, 100, 1), ("B", 10, 100, 100)
         )).toDF("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4")

val x = df.select("c1", "c2", "c3", "c4").rdd.map(x => (x.get(0),  List(x.get(1), x.get(2), x.get(3)))  )
val y = x.map {case (k, vL) => (k, vL.toSet.size) }
// Manipulate back to your DF, via conversion, join, what not.
```

Returns:

```
res15: Array[(Any, Int)] = Array((A,2), (F,3), (B,2))
```

Solution above better, as stated more so for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help for udf and you can do like this.

```
//Input
df.show
+-----------+
|CarrierCode|
+-----------+
|1:[12,2,12]|
|  2:[5,2,8]|
|  3:[1,1,3]|
+-----------+
//udf
 val countUDF=udf{(str:String)=>val strArr=str.split(":"); strArr(0)+":"+strArr(1).split(",").distinct.length.toString}

df.withColumn("Carrier Count",countUDF(col("CarrierCode"))).show

//Sample Output:
+-----------+-------------+
|CarrierCode|Carrier Count|
+-----------+-------------+
|1:[12,2,12]|          1:3|
|  2:[5,2,8]|          2:3|
|  3:[1,1,3]|          3:3|
+-----------+-------------+
```

Comment: If you provide schema and sample Input for your dataframe then I can help you better.